# Notification Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, уведомления

Цель такая, каждую минуту выполняется функция и по итогу пользователю выводится сообщение. Для этого использую Notification API.

```
var refresh = null;
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
   Notification.requestPermission();

function notificationShow(text) {

    var notification = new Notification('TITTLE', {
        icon: 'url to png',
        body: text
    });
}

refresh = setInterval(getInformation, 60000);

function getCurrentOrder() {

//получение значения information

   if (information > 0) {

       notificationShow('Информация А!');

   } else {

       notificationShow('Информация Б!');
   }

}
```

Допустим ситуацию, перезагрузили компьютер, открыли хром, заходим на страничку с данным скрипом. Не знаю уж от чего это зависит, может от фаз луны, но в начале (минут 10) все работает отлично, каждую минуту по 1 сообщению. Но потом происходит необъяснимое, появляется множество сообщений по 4 в минуту, потом по 5, в скором времени они вообще начинают накапливаться и постепенно выходить все. Вопрос. Что я делаю не так ? 
К слову, я думаю это важно, данный скрипт подключается к страничке через мое расширение ггул хрома.

Comment: Коротко: юзайте вложенный `setTimeout`. Длинно: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: refresh = setTimeout(function IntervalFunc(){ getCurrentOrder(); refreshOrders = setTimeout(refresh, 60000); }, 60000); Вот так сделал, все равно также проблема

Comment: Попробуйте запустить таймер для следующего уведомления лишь только после того как отработало отображение предыдущей нотификации.